# spring boot internationalization без jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, i18n

собственно можно ли юзать интернационализацию через набор файлов с ресурсами без jsp? в частности интересует angular 2. если да, то можно пожалуйста краткий примерчик или ссылочку, ничего толкового, увы, не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого нужно заинжектить бин типа [`MessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) и использовать его метод `getMessage()` для получения перевода.

[Пример](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/884cd70b4551eb85a9b89598df6313a2d8f8ba77/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/controller/CollectionController.java#L137).